# Date change halfway through csv from YYYY-MM-DD to DD/MM/YY and after switch datetime no longer works

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, datetime

I have a csv of daily temperature data with 3 columns: dates, daily maximum temperatures, and daily minimum temperatures. I attached it here so you can see what I mean.

I am trying to break this data set into smaller datasets of 30 year periods. For the first few years of Old.csv the dates are entered in YYYY-MM-DD but then switch to DD/MM/YY in 1900. After this date format switches my code to split the years no longer works. Here is what I'm using:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("Old.csv")

test = df2[
    (pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) >
        pd.to_datetime('1897-01-01')) &
    (pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) <
        pd.to_datetime('1899-12-31'))
]
```

and it works...BUT when I switch to 1900 and beyond it stops. So this one doesnt work:

```
test = df2[
    (pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) >
        pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')) &
    (pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) <
        pd.to_datetime('1905-12-31'))
]
```

The above code gives me an empty data set, despite working pre 1900. I'm assuming this is some sort of a formatting issue but I thought that using ".to_datetime" would fix that. I also tried this:

```
df2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
```

to reformat the entire list before I ran the code above but it still didnt work. The other interesting thing is that I have a separate csv with dates consistently entered as MM/DD/YY and that one works with the code above. Could it be an issue with the turn of the century? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: so you want to extract year value from the dates ?

Comment: How do you determine whether dates starting in 1900 are 19xx vs 20xx? For example if the data switches to DD/MM/YY from 1900 on, then how do you know if 02/05/02 is May 2, 1902 or May 2, 2002?

Comment: ah i should have said that the data set ends in 1968 so thats how i know its 1900 and not 2000

Comment: Thats the problem. The computer is reading 00 as 2000 instead of 1900. Does anyone know how to fix that without me going through every date and adding "19" before the year?

Comment: @MeganMartin maybe use the `date_parser` option of [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with time/date data with different formats, for this you could you could use a more flexible parser, for instance `dateutil.parser`

Example:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> df
         Date
0  1897-01-01
1  1899-12-31
2    01/01/00

>>> df.Date.apply(parse)
0   1897-01-01 00:00:00
1   1899-12-31 00:00:00
2            2000-01-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and use your function on the parsed data.

As remarked in the comment above, it's still not clear whether year "00" refers to year 1900 or 2000, but maybe you can infer that from the context of the csv file.

To change all years in the 'DD/MM/YY' format to 1900 dates you could define your own parse function

```
>>> def my_parse(d):
...   if d[-3]=='/':
...     d = d[:-3]+'/19'+d[-2:]
...   return parse(d)

>>> df.Date.apply(my_parse)
0   1897-01-01
1   1899-12-31
2   1900-01-01
```

Comment: I found the problem. The computer is reading 00 as 2000 instead of 1900. Does anyone know how to fix that without me going through every date and adding "19" before the year?

Comment: @MeganMartin please check the alternative solution

Comment: Yeah i tried that and this:modifications to a property of a datetimelike object are not supported and are discarded. Change values on the original.

Comment: oops didnt mean to comment that. I tried that and got this error: modifications to
a property of a datetimelike object are not supported and are discarded. C
hange values on the original. I also tried df2.Date.dt.year.replace(2000, 1990, inplace=True) but got the same message so I guess I'll have to go back and edit the original data

Answer (score 0):

Python is reading 00 as 2000 instead of 1900.  So I tried this to edit 00 to read as 1900:

```
df2.Date.dt.year.replace(2000, 1990, inplace=True)
```

But python returned an error that said dates are not directly editable. So I then changed them to a string and edited that way using:

```
df2['Date'] = df2['Date'].str.replace(r'00', '1900')
```

This works but now I need to find a way to loop through 1896-1968 without having to type that line out every time.